# HtmlAgilityPack Search line use next line

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I need a little bit support. I have grab with *C#* a website. Here is a short **HTML** what I need:

```
<div class="cf">
  <span class="labelText ohneFeldhilfe">Name</span>
  <p>Firstname Lastname</p>
</div>
<div class="cf">
  <span class="labelText ohneFeldhilfe">Created</span>
  <p>04/04/2016</p>
</div>
<div class="cf">
  <span class="labelText ohneFeldhilfe">Edit</span>
  <p>05/05/2016</p>
</div>
```

Is it possible with `HtmlAgilityPack` to grab the `Firstname` and `Lastname`? The problem, the `class="cf"` and the `class="labelText ohneFeldhilfe"` exist more than once in the HTML. I think it's neccessary to search for the whole row `<span class="labelText ohneFeldhilfe">Name</span>`.

Thanks for the support

Answer (score 1):

You can use either LINQ or XPath for this. Here I've done it with LINQ:

```
var html = "<div class=\"cf\">" +
            "    <span class=\"labelText ohneFeldhilfe\">Name</span>" +
            "    <p>Firstname Lastname</p>" +
            "</div>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var paragraphs = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div") // Get all divs..
    .Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value == "cf") // .. that have a class called cf ..
    .Select(d => d.Descendants("p").First()); // .. inside those divs select the first paragraph

foreach (var paragraph in paragraphs)
{
    var nameParts = paragraph.InnerText.Split(' ');

    Console.WriteLine("First name: " + nameParts[0]);
    Console.WriteLine("Last name: " + nameParts[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I have more than once DIV-tags and I need only Firstname and Lastname.

Comment: Would need to see more of the html then

Comment: I have changed the HTML above

Answer (score 0):

I have solved.

```
var paragraphs = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
    .Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value == "cf");

foreach (var paragraph in paragraphs)
{
  if(paragraph.InnerText.StartsWith("Name")) {
    Console.WriteLine("Found");
  };
}
```